# libcrypto++ in Linux

Tags: encryption

For the code:

```
#include <fstream>

#include <iostream> //cryptopp libraries

#include "cryptopp/dll.h"

#include "cryptopp/default.h"


using namespace std;

using namespace CryptoPP;

int main()
{

 byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH], iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];

    // initialize key and iv here

    CFB_Mode<AES >::Encryption cfbEncryption(key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv);

 std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

 return 0;

}
```

I have the following errors when compiling it:
 $: g++ test.cpp -o tess -lcrypto++ -lpthread

/tmp/ccLR085h.o: In function `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, true>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEjPKv[CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, true>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x2b): undefined reference to`CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsigned int)'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEjPKv[CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x38): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::UnalignedAllocate(unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccLR085h.o: In function`CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup::deallocate(void*, unsigned int)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPvj[CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup::deallocate(void*, unsigned int)]+0x25): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedDeallocate(void*)'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPvj[CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, true>::deallocate(void*, unsigned int)]+0x32): undefined reference to`CryptoPP::UnalignedDeallocate(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

NEED HELP. THX

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky. I suspect that the compile line you posted is not the compile line that produced the errors. When I do

```
g++ test.cpp -o tess -lcryptopp -lpthread -L.
```

I get no errors, but when I do

```
g++ -o tess -lcryptopp -lpthread -L. test.cpp
```

I get a lot of errors starting with

```
/tmp/ccCSTBSy.o: In function `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SimpleKeyingInterface()':
SO4602996.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP21SimpleKeyingInterfaceC2Ev[CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SimpleKeyingInterface()]+0x4): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface'
/tmp/ccCSTBSy.o: In function `CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false> >::SecBlock(unsigned int)':
SO4602996.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SecBlockIhNS_20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb0EEEEC1Ej[CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false> >::SecBlock(unsigned int)]+0x25): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)'
```

Which looks like the errors you were getting.

Please note that I compiled [cryptopp 5.6.1](http://www.cryptopp.com/) from source and placed a copy of the library in the directory I am using for this example: thus I need `-L.` to include the current directory in the Library path search. I am also using `-lcryptopp` instead of `-lcrypto++`, because that what my source produced.